# Weird green tick marks on icons on desktop

Tags: gnome, icons

I'm quite new to Ubuntu, in fact, just installed and set it up some hours ago. However, after installing some applications,
I realized all of my `.desktop` files have green tickmarks next to them.

What are these, and how can I disable them?

[image: Green Checkmarks]

Comment: Probably a silly question, but do you have Dropbox installed?

Comment: You only see these tickmarks on the desktop, i.e., not in the file manager when navigating to the "Desktop" folder?

Comment: Same "problem" here. Actually I have Dropbox installed, but I don't think it is related (Dropbox folder, e.g., has the green tick in different position and only when loading dropbox daemon)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the check marks are an indication that a Desktop Launcher has been marked as trusted. Without that the user is notified each time that the application is not trusted. So it seems this one "is not a bug, it is a feature" ;)